# On listview button click, log shows: "ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN"

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, button, logging

I have seen that many people have had this problem, but the solutions provided to them (like putting the layout inside another layout) did not work. Therefore I decided to upload my own code in the hope someone knows whats wrong with it. I have a listview with 2 buttons on each row (subtract_button & add_button), that is displayed using the following adapter class:

```
public class AdapterSIUsed2 extends CursorAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

private RowViewHolder rowView = new RowViewHolder();

public static class RowViewHolder {
    public TextView name,used,category,amount;
    public Button subtract,add;
    public int position;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case (rowView.add.getId()):
            // Do something
            Log.d("Button clicked","add");
            return;
        case (rowView.subtract.getId()):
            Log.d("Button clicked","subtract");
            return;
    }
}

public AdapterSIUsed2(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor csr, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout_shopping_items_used, null);
    rowView.name = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_name);
    rowView.used = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_used);
    rowView.category = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_category);
    rowView.amount = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_amount);
    rowView.subtract = (Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.subtract_button);
    rowView.add = (Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_add_button);
    rowView.position = csr.getPosition();
    rowView.subtract.setOnClickListener(this);
    rowView.add.setOnClickListener(this);
    listView.setTag(rowView);
    rowView.name.setTag(rowView);
    rowView.used.setTag(rowView);
    rowView.category.setTag(rowView);
    rowView.amount.setTag(rowView);
    return listView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_name);
    TextView used = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_used);
    TextView category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_category);
    TextView amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_amount);

    name.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(Constants.SHOPPING_ITEMS_COL_1)));
    used.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(Constants.SHOPPING_ITEMS_COL_2)));
    category.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(Constants.SHOPPING_ITEMS_COL_3)));
    amount.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(Constants.SHOPPING_ITEMS_COL_4)));

    Button add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shopping_items_add_button);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button subtract = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.subtract_button);
    subtract.setOnClickListener(this);

    int pos = csr.getPosition();
    add.setTag(pos);
    subtract.setTag(pos);
}
```

The strange thing is that when I click the add or the subtract button, in both cases my log show the following two lines:
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/item clicked: :(
And when I click the list item itself, my log only displays the following line:
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Does anyone know what is going on here and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACTION_DOWN` just means that something was pressed. It's related to `ACTION_UP`, which means something is not being pressed any more.

Evidently, the buttons you're pressing are the ones you set in `bindView`. It's not clear why you're getting that behavior when you click the list item itself; it doesn't look like you're setting any `onClickListeners` on the cell itself, or any kind of parent `ViewGroup`. You might want to double check and make sure that your layout IDs are what they are supposed to be. It's also possible that whatever is using this as an adapter is messing with things.

It seems like you're getting the correct behavior with your `onClick` method overridden from the interface implementation. Even if it gives you extra information, it is logging what you asked it to ("item clicked: :("). I suggest just using that, and changing the log to use `Log.d` instead (`Log.d` is specifically for debugging purposes). You could also do something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == rowView.add.getId()) {
            //do something;
            return;
        if (v.getId() == rowView.subtract.getId()) {
            //do something;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

and then you just do

```
rowView.add.setOnClickListener(this);
rowView.subtract.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your reply. I tried my best to understand what you said and I edited my code in a few ways but unfortunately without success. In the question is my current code. In the lines with the "cases", it tells me "constant expression required", do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. You can't put something that might change in a case statement- it has to be constant. In that case, just use a normal if statement. I'll edit my post to be more clear about how that would work.

Comment: Very nice, what is gives me now is the following: press subtract button; "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN" and "D/Button clicked: subtract", press add button; "ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN" and "D/Button clicked: add", press somewhere else in the listview item; "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN". So it does recognize the buttons now. I hope that the fact that it still gives the ACTION_DOWN does not matter, do you know if it does?

Comment: also, when I try to add an action like create a toast when the button is clicked, but then it tells me that a non-static method cannot be referenced from non-static context

Comment: Can you please help me? ^^